# qgis_version_2: add layer or group of layers always on the top of the legendInterface / Insert the layer at the top of the ToC

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I have a code which is adding raster layer or group of raster layers, it's working fine.

I want to know if there is a way to add layer or group of the layers always on the top of the  legend Interface?

```
root = self.iface.legendInterface()
if status: # True
    group = root.addGroup("Group")
    layer = self.iface.addRasterLayer(urlWithParams, "new_layer", "wms")
    root.moveLayer(layer,group) 

else: # False
    self.iface.addRasterLayer(urlWithParams, "new_layer", "wms")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for unique solution that will work in QGIS 2.x and QGIS 3.x:

add layer or group of layers always on the top of the legendInterface / Insert the layer or group of layers at the top of the ToC.

How **QgsProject class is not available in QGIS 2.x**, here is the solution I was looking for:

```
    try:
        # QGis 3.x
        root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

    except:
        # QGis 2.x
        root = self.iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup()


    # the rest of the code is the same for QGis version 2.x and 3.x
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, "new_layer", "wms")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(raster_layer, False)

    # Insert group with layer on the top of the legendInterface
    layer = QgsLayerTreeLayer(raster_layer)
    group = root.insertGroup(0, "new_group")
    group.insertChildNode(0, layer)

    # insert layer on the top of the legendInterface
    root.insertLayer(0, raster_layer)
```

code is tested with QGis 2.18 Las Pamas and QGis 3.4 Madeira

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, somebody wrote a plugin just for that!!! :)

Have a look at the [New layers to the top](https://github.com/gacarrillor/NewLayersToTheTop) plugin. You can check it first as a user and then examine the code and borrow a couple of lines that you probably need for your Python code, namely:

```
def changeLayerAdditionMode( self, layers ):          
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRegistryBridge().setLayerInsertionPoint( QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), 0 )

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersAdded.connect( self.changeLayerAdditionMode )
```

Comment: tnx for advice but QgsProject class is not available in QGis 2.x

Comment: QgsProject exists in QGIS v2.x (see [api docs v2.0](https://qgis.org/api/2.0/classQgsProject.html)). I created the plugin specifically for QGIS 2.

Comment: Thnak you, I test it, its really nice solution! :) @Germán Carrillo